# Sending WhatsApp template using Freshchat custom app

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, postman

I'm creating a custom app inside Freshchat to send WhatsApp templates and faced the mentioned error
and it is working normally from Postman.

```html
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

dec:

> [text](https://developers.freshdesk.com/v2/docs/request-method/#configure_request_templates)

Request code:

```json
{
"send_msg":{
    "schema":{
        "method":"POST",
        "host":"api.freshchat.com",
        "path":"/api/v2/outbound-messages/whatsapp",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxx",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
    }
}
}
```

Appreciate your kind support to finalize it and remove the error and send the messsage.

I want the right code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use in ruby you can use this gem https://rubygems.org/gems/freshchat_whatsapp

also if you want to use curl you can use

```
curl --location 'https://example.freshchat.com/v2/outbound-messages/whatsapp' \
--header 'accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  '\''from'\'': {
    '\''phone_number'\'': '\''+919198XXXXXXXX'\''
  },
  '\''to'\'': [
    {
      '\''phone_number'\'': '\''+9198XXXXXXXX'\''
    }
  ],
  '\''data'\'': {
    '\''message_template'\'': {
      '\''storage'\'': '\''conversation'\'',
      '\''namespace'\'': '\''namespace'\'',
      '\''template_name'\'': '\''corporate_sales_client_phone_number_verification'\'',
      '\''language'\'': {
        '\''policy'\'': '\''deterministic'\'',
        '\''code'\'': '\''en'\''
      },
      '\''rich_template_data'\'': {
        '\''button'\'': {
          '\''subType'\'': '\''url'\'',
          '\''params'\'': [
            {
              '\''data'\'': '\''/en/testing2123123$#'\''
            }
          ]
        },
        '\''body'\'': {
          '\''params'\'': [
              {
              '\''data'\'': '\''Test data'\''
            }
           ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```